# (L'Étranger de Camus) Use of pronoun "le" in "Je l’avais pour ainsi dire oublié"

Tags: pronoms

The question is on the pronoun "le" (highlighted) in this passage from Camus's *The Stranger*.

> En me réveillant, j’ai compris pourquoi mon patron avait l’air mécontent quand je lui ai demandé mes deux jours de congé : c’est aujourd’hui samedi. Je **l’avais** pour ainsi dire oublié, mais en me levant, cette idée m’est venue. Mon patron, tout naturellement, a pensé que j’aurais ainsi quatre jours de vacances avec mon dimanche et cela ne pouvait pas lui faire plaisir. Mais d’une part, ce n’est pas de ma faute si on a enterré maman hier au lieu d’aujourd’hui et d’autre part, j’aurais eu mon samedi et mon dimanche de toute façon. Bien entendu, cela ne m’empêche pas de comprendre tout de même mon patron.

With the help of English translations, I am understanding it to mean "I have forgotten it while thus saying."  For that to be correct, *le* would have to refer to it being Saturday today, and *ainsi* to asking for two days off. (I will post a separate question on *pour*.)

Assuming I am OK so far, I have this question:

If we replace *le* with *ce*, would that be grammatical or ungrammatical and, if grammatical, awkward or natural sounding?

My motivation for asking the question is:  A grammar book has told me that *ce* is used for reference to a statement already made while *le* anticipates a statement to come.  According to this, it being Saturday today (as already mentioned) would be *ce*.  Examples from the grammar book:

> Partir avant l'aube?  C'est possible.
>
> Il m'est difficile d'accepter sa proposition.

Comment: Really quick (somebody will have something more complete, I'm sure): "_pour ainsi dire_" is an idiom. "_Ce_" is OK when used as a subject ("_*C'*est possible._"). When used as a complement, you turn to "_le/la/les_" : "_Je *l'*avais oublié._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *le* is the clitic pronoun used for phrasal complements. Possessing no person, no gender and no number as such, they are pronominalized with the default value for each attribute : 3SG, M and SG.

- **Fumer tue**, je *le* savais.
- Paul est **intelligent** et Marie *l*'est aussi.
- Georges **a acheté son ticket** hier, et Amélie *le* fera demain.